# Where magento store data from account info on order page

Tags: magento-enterprise, orders, customer-attribute

Where does magento store the data which is shown in the block `Account information` in `adminarea` in `order edit page`?

Answer (score 1):

in the `sales_flat_order` table as the rest of the order details.
A field values shows under the `Account Information` tab if the field name from the table starts with `customer_`. You can see this in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info::getCustomerAccountData`

Comment: Yes, in described model I saw this method. I see that all data is taken from order, but these data is already in order. When it appear there? And I can't find any my account info in `sales_flat_order`. Maybe I have customized magento...

Comment: In addition. I have custom customer attribute (its magento EE). I changed this attr on order creation page in admin area. This attribute wasn't changed in customer account. Also I created SQL dump and did search for my value_id and didn't find it there.

Answer (score 0):

Found..

These values are here: `enterprise_customer_sales_flat_order`

On order afterLoad execute following:

> Enterprise_Customer_Model_Observer

```
/**
 * After load observer for order
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Enterprise_Customer_Model_Observer
 */
public function salesOrderAfterLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if ($order instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Abstract) {
        Mage::getModel('enterprise_customer/sales_order')
            ->load($order->getId())
            ->attachAttributeData($order);
    }

    return $this;
}
```